# Executing a Django Shell Command from the Command Line

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I would like to execute a command via Django's manage.py shell function solely from the command line

e.g.

```
manage.py shell -c "from myapp import models; print models.MyModel.some_calculation()"
```

the came way you might use the -c option with the normal Python interpreter

e.g.

```
python -c "print 'hello world'"
```

However, I don't see an equivalent -c option for `manage.py shell`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please don't.  Please write a two-line script file.

Comment: [see custom admin commands](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not like that. But it is easy enough to write a [standalone script for Django](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).

Comment: Links tend to expire... code example here is better.

Answer (score 46):

[Pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) it ;)

```sh
echo "print('hello world')" | python manage.py shell
```

Comment: or if you want to use a file:
`cat my_script.py | python manage.py shell`

Comment: I'm not sure why, but that isn't working for me. I'm forced to use `echo "$(cat my_script.py)" | python manage.py shell` instead.

Comment: Correction, indentation doesn't work with IPython, so to force the standard prompt: `... | python manage.py shell -i python`

Comment: Make sure you include a `\n` at the end (with `echo -e` if necessary).